# Intrinsic/Monitor Locks and Inheritance

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, locking, monitor

**Background:**

I'm reading Java Concurrency in Practice, and Listing 2.7 has the following code.  The example states that this code only functions because monitor locks are re-entrant.

I would have *originally* thought that when you called `super.doSomething()` then it would have acquired a lock on the base class object and not the derived class object.  That would mean this situation would not require re-entrancy.  Having said this, I also understand that both base class and derived class methods can alter base class fields, so the lock they use must be common *(meaning I was obviously mistaken)*.

**Question:**

*Is there one "intrinsic" lock per object in an inheritance hierarchy, or one "intrinsic" lock associated with the most derived object (or least derived object) in the hierarchy only?*

---

```
public class Widget {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}

public class LoggingWidget extends Widget {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(toString() + ": calling doSomething");
        super.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would have originally thought that when you called super.doSomething() then it would have acquired a lock on the base class object and not the derived class object.

There's only one object - if you create an instance of `LoggingWidget`, there's only *one* object created, with all the fields from `LoggingWidget` and *also* all the fields from `Widget`. It's not like it creates an instance of `LoggingWidget` that refers to an instance of `Widget`.

There's only one object, and therefore only one lock, wherever you synchronize on it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Out of curiosity, does C++ work similarly, or are they different in this regard?

Comment: iirc, this is one of the (many!) areas that C++ is "implementation-specific." But most if not all implementations just have one object, too. That said, the memory that the object lives in is usually segmented into different blocks, one for each class in the hierarchy.

Comment: Ah, that explains my confusion a little :).  I was pretty sure that in "Effective C++" they stated that if you don't make base class constructors virtual, you can end up deleting the base class memory and leaving the derived class memory as a memory leak which made me assume they're different objects entirely.  I just mentally carried it over to Java I guess.

Comment: @w00te: that’s not really comparable as in C++ there is no intrinsic lock…

Comment: @Holger - Yeah in C++ you'd have to use a mutex.  I was just curious about class instantiation in C++ in general :).  Thanks for the warning though!